# Erlang - use of lists when the size is consistently changing over time

Tags: erlang, ipc, erlang-shell

I am new to Erlang and I am learning by building a really small chat program in pure Erlang.

I would like for clients to be able to connect to a server and then send messages to each other. But this is all done on a local machine and not over a network just for learning.

I have a list of all the clients that have connected to the server.

If client A sends a message to client B, I get the desired output in client A's terminal but I can't work out how to get the message from client A to be displayed on client B's terminal.

Or do I have to set each client with it's own mini server

```
-module(server).
-export([start/0]).
-export([server/1]).
-export([connect/0]).
-export([sendMessage/2]).

%%
%% The Server 
%%
start() ->
    EmptyList = [],
    Pid = spawn(server, server, [EmptyList]),
    register(chatServe, Pid).

server(ListOfClients) ->
    receive
        {Client, connect} ->
            Client ! {chatServe, connected},
            List = clientList(ListOfClients, Client),
            server(List);

        {Client, message, MessageBody} ->
            List = ListOfClients,
            lists:foreach(fun(X) -> X ! {chatServe, new_message, MessageBody} end, List),
            Client ! {chatServe, received},
            server(List)
    end.

%%
%% The client will call rpc:call(server@local, server, connect, [])
%% to connect
%%
connect() ->
    chatServe ! {self(), connect},
    receive
        {chatServe, connected} -> connected
    end.

%%
%% The send message method takes two args
%%
%%
sendMessage(SendTo, MessageBody) ->
    chatServe ! {self(), message, MessageBody},
    receive
       {chatServe, received} -> received
    end.

receiveMessage(SendTo, SendFrom, MessageBody) ->
    receive
        {}
    end.


%% 
%% Some helper functions
%%

clientList(List, Client) when length(List) =:= 0 ->
    io:format("List Size = 1~n"),
    [Client];
clientList(List, Client) ->
    io:format("List size = ~p~n", [length(List) + 1]),
    [Client | List].



forwardMessage(SendTo, SentFrom, MessageBody, [H | T]) when H =:= SendTo ->
    SendTo ! {SentFrom, message, MessageBody};
forwardMessage(SendTo, SentFrom, MessageBody, [H | T]) -> 
    forwardMessage(SendTo, SentFrom, MessageBody, T);
forwardMessage(SendTo, SentFrom, MessageBody, []) -> [].
```

In the terminal of the client I am calling 
    rpc:call(host, mod, function, args).

So my question is how can I get Client A to send a message to Client B through server C, with Client A displaying success, and Client B displaying the message that was sent?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not an answer but I have put here an example of chat with some comments https://github.com/pascalchap/minichat

Comment: @Pascal Thanks for your response.  It seems as though you made use of a listen loop for each client.  Yep that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example my server is an Erlang node and every client is an erlang node too.

Code:

```
-module(test).
-export([server_start/1, client_start/2]).
-export([server_new_message/2, client_new_message/2]).








server_start(ServerName) ->
    {ok, _Pid} = net_kernel:start([ServerName, shortnames]),
    erlang:register(server, erlang:self()),
    io:format("Server '~p' started.~nMessages: ~n ~n", [erlang:node()]), 
    server_loop().






server_loop() ->
    receive
        {msg, Name, Text} ->
            io:format("~p: ~p~n", [Name, Text]),
            Receivers = lists:delete(Name, erlang:nodes()),
            rpc:multicall(Receivers, ?MODULE, client_new_message, [Name, Text]),
            server_loop()
    end.




%% Server runs this function in client's node.
%% 'client' process in client's node will receive this message and print it
client_new_message(Name, Text) ->
    client ! {msg, Name, Text}.





client_start(ServerName, ClientName) ->
    {ok, _Pid} = net_kernel:start([ClientName, shortnames]),
    pong = net_adm:ping(ServerName),
    timer:sleep(1000), % wait for updating erlang:nodes()
    Other = lists:delete(ServerName, erlang:nodes()),
    io:format("Client '~p' connected to server '~p'.~nOnline users: ~p~n", [erlang:node(), ServerName, Other]),
    erlang:register(client, spawn_link(fun print/0)),
    client_loop(ServerName).





print() ->
    receive
        {msg, Name, Text} ->
            io:format("~p: ~p~n", [Name, Text]),
            print()
    end.





client_loop(ServerName) ->
    rpc:call(ServerName, ?MODULE, server_new_message, [erlang:node(), io:get_line(">>> ")]),
    client_loop(ServerName).




%% Clients run this function in server's node
%% 'server' process will receive messages and print them and broadcast them
server_new_message(Name, Text) ->
    server ! {msg, Name, Text}.
```

Run:

I open 3 Erlang shells.
In shell **1** i run server:

```
p@jahanbakhsh ~/Desktop $ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2.2] [source-1ca84a4] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.2.2  (abort with ^G)
1> test:server_start(local_chat_server).
Server 'local_chat_server@jahanbakhsh' started.
Messages:
```

Server is waiting for messages.

In shell **2** i run client 1:

```
p@jahanbakhsh ~/Desktop $ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2.2] [source-1ca84a4] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.2.2  (abort with ^G)
1> test:client_start('local_chat_server@jahanbakhsh', client_1).
Client 'client_1@jahanbakhsh' connected to server 'local_chat_server@jahanbakhsh'.
Online users: []
>>>
```

Now i can send message from this terminal, but wait.
I run client 2 in shell **3**:

```
p@jahanbakhsh ~/Desktop $ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2.2] [source-1ca84a4] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.2.2  (abort with ^G)
1> test:client_start('local_chat_server@jahanbakhsh', client_2).
Client 'client_2@jahanbakhsh' connected to server 'local_chat_server@jahanbakhsh'.
Online users: [client_1@jahanbakhsh]
>>>
```

I send a message ("Test message") from shell **2** or client 1.
In shell **1** or server i have:

```
client_1@jahanbakhsh: "Test message\n" - sent to [client_2@jahanbakhsh]
```

In shell **3** or client 2 i have:

```
client_1@jahanbakhsh: "Test message\n"
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I did manage to get it sorted in the end and it seemed to be a mix of both yours and Pascals answer.  ;)